# Can we set up a database on Amazon EC2 similar to how XAMPP is configured on my local system

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2

Can you install MySQL for AWS Elastic Cloud Compute (EC2) directly on the instance? I can't afford to purchase a separate RDS instance at the moment.

My website is setup on AWS EC2 already and now I'm going to try out some features with a database. I need to set up the instance to run on the EC2 localhost and connect it to my website to store my user data.

Answer (score 0):

So first you need to separate XAMPP from mysql in your thought process. XAMPP is a tool only for your local development. You can set up a database on the Elastic Cloud Compute (EC2) instance similarly to how you set up your XAMPP config locally.

Here are the official docs on how to install a full LAMP stack on an EC2 instance running the Amazon Linux AMI - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Comment: LAMP will be suit for my MICROSOFT SEVER AMI

Comment: You're using an IIS instance or a different AMI? Can you link the AMI?

Comment: i'm using IIS for my server

Comment: Is there a reason for IIS when you're using XAMPP? Are you only using XAMPP for MySql?

Comment: what language is your application written in?

Comment: php for accesing database  and htmlt and css for website

Comment: To be honest I'm not very familiar with IIS. Is there a reason you chose IIS for your server? I'd switch to a linux-based server for your application even if you're doing development on a windows unless you have a specific need for IIS like doing ASP.net or C#